# element not updating value on html Polymer V3

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-3.x, lit-element

I want to update the todoList in my PARENT COMPONENT after I have added a new item in my child using the `AddItem()` method. Nothing gets added the first time.
EX. if I add "take test" doesn't get render, then if I add "take shower" doesn't get rendered but now "take test" does. Then if I add "take a leak" "take shower" gets rendered.

**PARENT COMPONENT**

```
firstUpdated(changedProperties) {
    this.addEventListener('addItem', e => {
      this.todoList = e.detail.todoList;
    });
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <p>Todo App</p>
      <add-item></add-item>//Child item that triggers the add
      <list-items todoList=${JSON.stringify(this.todoList)}></list-items>
    `;
  }
```

**CHILD COMPONENT**

```
AddItem() {
    if (this.todoItem.length > 0) {
      let storedLocalList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo-list'));
      storedLocalList = storedLocalList === null ? [] : storedLocalList;
      const todoList = [
        ...storedLocalList,
        {
          id: this.uuidGenerator(),
          item: this.todoItem,
          done: false
        }
      ];

      localStorage.setItem('todo-list', JSON.stringify(todoList));
      this.dispatchEvent(
        new CustomEvent('addItem', {
          bubbles: true,
          composed: true,
          detail: { todoList: storedLocalList }
        })
      );
      this.todoItem = '';
    }
  }

  render() {
    return html`
      <div>
        <input .value=${this.todoItem} @keyup=${this.inputKeyup} />
        <button @click="${this.AddItem}">Add Item</button>
      </div>
    `;
  }
```

Comment: Try writing `eventlistener` in connected call back instead.. or approach 2: replace this.addEventLister to document.addEventListener..

Comment: Is the problem that no event is being dispatched or that no item is being added to the list? Could you edit your question to include a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We can't reproduce the issue in order to help you solve it because, for example, you've omitted the code that updates `this.todoItem` (which I can only assume is in `this.inputKeyup`).

Comment: As an aside, is there a reason you chose to bind the event listener in `firstUpdated` rather than doing so in the template, e.g. `<child-element @add-item=${this.handleAddItem}>`?

Comment: @shabarinath I have updated the code. The code is not adding the item to the list BUT only when I add an item again. EX. if I add "take test" doesn't get render, then if I add "take shower" doesn't get rendered but now "take test" does.

Comment: @JordanRunning uhmm nope. This is my first app with Polymer so obviously I have no clue what I'm doing lol. I have updated my question

Comment: @JordanRunning I did this ```<add-item @addItem=${this.handleAddItem}></add-item>``` and still experiencing the rending issue

Comment: @PatricioVargas why do u need localstorage., Also., have you initailised `todoItem` in `static get properties` ?.. like `static get properties() { return { todoItem: {type: Array, Observer: '_itemsUpdated' }}`., in `_itemsUpdated` ., `_itemsUpdated(newValue,oldValue){if(newValue){-- write your code here.. no event listeners required}}`.. one more point., dont forget to initialise `todoitem` in `constructor`.. `constructor(){ this.todoItem = [] }`.. constructor just initialises. Observer observe changes to array & triggers function. there u can update your array

Comment: @PatricioVargas perhaps this blog https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com can help you understanding polymer for starters. Since you are curious., this blog has some related posts which can give solution to your questions.

Comment: @shabarinath local storage is just for this example to store the data somewhere. This is my first polymer app so I just felt like using localstorage and yes. I have set the todoList array in my properties and initialized it in the constructor. Can you put that comment in an answer please? Thanks so much! ill look at your blog

Comment: @PatricioVargas Thanks Iam helpful. Perhaps you can accept my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found my error. I was passing to detail: { todoList : storedLocalList } which is the old array without the updated value.

```
 AddItem() {
        if (this.todoItem.length > 0) {
          let storedLocalList = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('todo-list'));
          storedLocalList = storedLocalList === null ? [] : storedLocalList;
          const todoList = [
            ...storedLocalList,
            {
              id: this.uuidGenerator(),
              item: this.todoItem,
              done: false
            }
          ];

          localStorage.setItem('todo-list', JSON.stringify(todoList));
          this.dispatchEvent(
            new CustomEvent('addItem', {
              bubbles: true,
              composed: true,
              detail: { todoList: todoList }
            })
          );
          this.todoItem = '';
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `properties` for `todoItem`

```js
static get properties() {

  return { 
    todoItem: {
    type: Array, 
    Observer: '_itemsUpdated' 
    }
  }
  constructor(){ 
    this.todoItem = [] 
  }
  _itemsUpdated(newValue,oldValue){
  if(newValue){
    -- write your code here.. no event listeners required
    }
  }
```

In above code., We need to initialise empty array in `constructor`.

`Observer` observe the changes to array & triggers `itemsUpdated` function which carries oldValue & NewValue. In that function., you can place your logic.

No Event Listeners required as per my assumption

Comment: but how am I sending the updated array all the way to the parent component?

Comment: @PatricioVargas sry., i was in assumption that it was single component while answering. you can keep eventListeners and use `requestUpdate` method for DOM re rendering in `lit-html` (as i can see you are trying to combine Polymer & Lit from your code).. `this.addEventListener('addItem', e => {
      this.todoList = e.detail.todoList;
      this.requestUpdate();
    });`.. see lit-html life cycle here.. https://lit-element.polymer-project.org/guide/lifecycle